# MASE calculation using accuracy function from forecast package in r

Tags: r, forecasting

Regarding Forecasting in R...

1. I have applied Naive forecasting method for some data using loop function, then I tried to found "MAPE"  it is successful.

   ```
   MAPE_N1<- matrix(NA, nrow=52, ncol=ncol(TS), 
             dimnames = list(c(Weeks),c(colnames(Master_Data[,-1]))))
   for(i in 1:ncol(TS)) {
     MAPE_N1[,i] <- accuracy(as.vector(F1_N[,i]),TS)["Test set", "MAPE"]
   }
   ```
2. But when tried same setup for MASE just by changing "MASE"  instead of MAPE  I am getting error.

   ```
   MAPE_N1 <- matrix(NA, nrow=52, ncol=ncol(TS), 
              dimnames = list(c(Weeks),c(colnames(Master_Data[,-1]))))
   for(i in 1:ncol(TS)) {
     MAPE_N1[,i] <- accuracy(as.vector(F1_N[,i]),TS)["Test set", "MASE"]
   }
   ```

> error description:     Error in accuracy(as.vector(F1_N[, i]),
>   TS)["Test set", "MASE"] : 
>       subscript out of bounds

Note: I'm getting out put for all other errors in accuracy function except MASE.

Please help me to solve this.

Regards 
Munikumar

Comment: Can you please provide the `dput` output of `F1_N` and `TS` ?

Comment: Hi Macro Sandri.  Thanks for your reply.                                                                           "F1_N" is naive forecast which has applied for the time series "TS".

Comment: Coding for "TS"                                                                                                      TS<- ts(Master_Data[,-1],start=c(2014,26),frequency = 365.25/7)                           Coding for "F1_N"                                                                                           F1_N<- matrix(NA,nrow=52,ncol=ncol(TS),dimnames = list(c(Weeks),c(colnames(Master_Data[,-1]))))
for(i in 1:ncol(TS))
{
  F1_N[,i] <- naive(TS[,i], h=52)$mean
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MASE can only be computed if the training data is available. If the first argument in `accuracy` is a `forecast` object, then it will find the training data and compute MASE. But if you give it a vector of forecasts rather than an object of class `forecast`, then the training data is not available, and MASE cannot be computed.

Comment: Thank You Professor for your kind reply!!.                                                                                                As per your suggestion i removed "as.vector function". Corrected  code                                                                             MAPE_N1<- matrix(NA,nrow=52,ncol=ncol(TS),dimnames = list(c(Weeks),c(colnames(Master_Data[,-1]))))

for(i in 1:ncol(TS)){
  MAPE_N1[,i] <- accuracy(F1_N[,i],TS)["Test set", "MASE"]
}